# Fancytree and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, fancytree

I am trying to use fancytree in a backbone.js application.

I am getting the following error:

TypeError: $(...).fancytree is not a function

when it hits this line in the backbone.js view:

var myTree = $("#buildingsTree").fancytree({

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have required the fancytree js files before your view gets loaded, as per https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#user-content-embed-fancytree-on-your-web-page
- Make sure you are using a compatible jQuery version: "Required minimum versions are jQuery 1.7+ and jQuery UI 1.8.6+" https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#user-content-getting-started