# Fancytree not rendering in backbone templated page

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, fancytree

I'm having the same problem  as this [Fancytree and Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016054/fancytree-and-backbone)

My fancytree is not showing up in my page with backbone. I'm using jquery v2.1.3 and fancytree 2.8.1, and I definitely have the fancytree js loaded before my view. The same exact view js and html code work in a separate test page I have set up without backbone.

Note that if the tree div is drawn directly on the page and not in a handlebar, it renders perfectly.

Note that I am using backbone marionette.

Suggestions?

Comment: I am debugging and I find that when I put the div OUTSIDE of backbone, I can put a breakpoint in the _create function of fancytree.  This gets called and I see the call stack that goes from jquery-ui in the e.widget.bridge.e.fn, through jquery each, through e.Widget._createWidget and then calls the $widget._create.  If I am using backbone, the createWidget never gets called.  Perhaps this is a jquery problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Problem solved.

Jquery was not returning the correct div when I simply wrote:

```
var layertreeNode = $("#layertree");
```

Instead if I looked within the backbone class for the div it found it and fancytree rendered in the div:

```
var layertreeNode = this.$el.find("#layertree");
```